# Cannot set content-type in header for azure pipelines task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am building azure pipeline task which is calling an endpoint. However I keep getting error "unsupportedmediatype 415". here is my code

```
   "dataSources": [
    {
      "name": "ProjectsEP",     

       "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/api/project/projects",
       "requestVerb": "Post",
       "resultSelector": "jsonpath:",
       "requestContent":"",
       "headers": [
       {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
     ] 
 }

"dataSourceBindings": [
  {
   "target": "project",
   "endpointId": "$(FabrikamService)",
   "dataSourceName": "ProjectsEP",
    "requestVerb": "Post"
  }]
```

I need to change the content-type to "application/json".

The same request works in postman
[image: same request in Postman]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following format to set the headers and check if it could work:

```
"headers": "{\n\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\", \n\"Authorization\": \"Bearer  $(system.accesstoken)\"\n}"
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/blob/1cc151a985776fed1531738d4a69a59dfc7d4cd1/extensions/sonarcloud/tasks/qgstatus/new/task.json), you could refer to it.